# Ajax and post on php

Tags: php, ajax, post

hello i think i'm missing something here... I have that script on my html page

```
12     <script type="text/javascript">
 13         $(document).ready(function() {
 14                 $('#find').click(function(){
 15                         
 16                         var amount = $('#amount').val();
 17 
 18                         $.ajax({
 19                                 type: "POST",
 20                                 url: "questions.php",
 21                                 data: amount,
 22                                 success: function(data){
 23                                         
 24                                         $('#results').show();
 25                         
 26                                         
 27                                         $('#results').html(data);
 28                                 }
 29                         });
 30                 });
 31         });
 32     </script>
```

if i alert amount i get the input so the value works fine

and here is my php script

```
<?php
  2 $search_term = $_POST['amount'];
  3 
  4 
  5 
  6 echo $search_term;

...
```

so i get nothing as a result!
if i change the echo thing to "mpla mpla"; everything works fine?

Am l missing something?

thanks in advance!

Comment: As a picky side note, you should assume that array keys exist on any kind of user controlled input.  You should user either filter_input or isset to ensure that you don't try to access an array key that doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah i know that that is a simplified version of my code! just the problem i had!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 14                 $('#find').click(function(){
 15                         
 16                         var amount = $('#amount').val();
 17 
 18                         $.ajax({
 19                                 type: "POST",
 20                                 url: "questions.php",
 21                                 data: { 'amount': amount },
 22                                 success: function(data){
 23                                         
 24                                         $('#results').show();
 25                         
 26                                         
 27                                         $('#results').html(data);
 28                                 }
 29                         });
 30                 });
 31         });
```

Change it into this. This will pass the variable 'amount' as `$_REQUEST['amount']`

Answer (score 3):

`data` is meant to be a map of keys and values.

Try:

```
data: {amount: amount}
```